# Why do I have to install RMarkdown to knit?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have the RMarkdown package installed, even though I read that RStudio (4.0.2) installs it and loads it anyway.

I run my chunks and everything works fine, but when I come to knit, R opens the RMarkdown console, with this error, even though I can see it's installed.

I have found similar questions about this error with other packages, but RMarkdown is critical to the knit process so I don't get why Knit throws the following error message:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
> Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
> Execution halted

Where do I need to install the rmarkdown package to?

`SystemInfo()` shows it is loaded:

> other attached packages:
> [1] ggplot2_3.3.2 tidyr_1.1.2   rmarkdown_2.3 dplyr_1.0.2

Comment: Perhaps check `.libPaths()` in RStudio console.

Comment: thanks - but rmarkdown package is present in both locations that libPaths mentions

Comment: What happens if you use `rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd', output_dir = ..., output_file = ..., quiet = F)`?

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked.  I discovered that render command works from console, despite that the knit button did not work, so I've reinstalled knitr and everything is ok now.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue might be the letters in the folder your file and or program is in? I had an issue with ä, ö, ü being in those once and got the same error message, maybe it is that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30794939)